How is a right angle practically set up when trying to prove that some space is curved
About curved space, Wikipedia says

One of the defining characteristics of a curved space is its departure from the Pythagorean theorem, $dx^2 + dy^2\neq dl^2$.

This relies on being able to constructively set up a "right angle". Other constructive tests of intrinsic curvature are similar, like sum of triangle angles $\neq 180°$ or 4 right angles don't close a square.
Now suppose I am that often cited ant on a sphere: I set up a triangle with one right angle and literally walk along the three sides to check Pythagoras' theorem.
Assume I know how to draw straight lines (geodesics) and measure lengths along them.
What is the correct way to set up the right angle? The theoretical answer would involve a scalar product being zero. But there should be a geometric construction involving straight lines and lengths, maybe:

Take a same sided triangle, find the middle of one side and from there draw through the opposing vertex.

Draw a circle and divide the radius into 4 equals parts.


Are these OK? Is there a better way?

You should not trust Wikipedia on such matters (the first sentence of your post is simply wrong). I suggest reading a differential geometry textbook instead.

Your two approaches only work on spaces of constant curvature. Think of the manifold as a surface with rolling hills and valleys. If your point of intersection is on the side of a hill, the distortions from flat differ in different directions. Thus you cannot define angle measures macroscopically. Manifolds are locally Euclidean, so the closer you look at the vertex where the geodesics cross, the closer the crossed geodesics resemble a Euclidean angle. The measure of that limiting Euclidean angle is the measure assigned to the geodesic angle.

Is the question, in effect, In a Riemannian manifold, define a "Straightedge" to be a geodesic segment and a "Compass" to be a geodesic circle. How can we give a Straightedge and Compass construction of a right angle at an arbitrary point relative to an arbitrary geodesic? <> If so, it looks to me that in general, taking limits must be part of the construction.

One approach is to use a "parallelogram" instead of a right angle.
Construct this quadrilateral as follows:
Draw two lines through a point $O$. From $O$ mark off points $A$ and $B$ at equal distances and opposite directions along one of the drawn lines. Mark off $C$ and $D$ in similar manner along the second line. Connect $A,B,C,D$ in rotational order to define the sides of the quadrilateral.
In Euclidean geometry the result is a parallelogram, and the Pythagorean Theorem implies that the sum of the squared diagonals ($AB^2+CD^2$) equals the sum of all four sides squared ($AC^2+BC^2+AD^2+BD^2$). But, for instance, on a sphere the sum of the squared diagonals measures out to greater than the sum of the squared sides.
